# Lightning Security CRUD operations example code doesn't compile correctly

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Trying to use the following example here https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Security

The article promotes best practice to perform field level security access check on lightning @AuraEnabled CRUD methods.

The example code fails in the compiler as unexpected return statement.  So I figured they forgot a ';' after throwing the exception.  This is not correct as then the return method becomes an unreachable statement.

Any insight into what the author was trying to achieve here 'comment quiet the editor'?  Imagine this has to do with cryptic error messages?

```
 // Check if the user has access to view field
      if (!m.get(fieldToCheck).getDescribe().isAccessible()) {

           //also pass error to client
           throw new System.NoAccessException()

           //included to quiet editor
           return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing Author meant here two scenarios,

- In case you want to thrown an error on front end if the user does not have access to the field then use below code

  ```
  // Check if the user has access to view field
   if (!m.get(fieldToCheck).getDescribe().isAccessible()) {

     //also pass error to client
     throw new AuraHandledException('You have no access to field '+fieldToCheck);

  }
  ```
- In case you don't want to pass any error th
  Message to the client and just do nothing when you have no access to the field

  ```
     // Check if the user has access to view field
     if (!m.get(fieldToCheck).getDescribe().isAccessible()) {
          //return to the front end without providing exception
          return null;
      }
  ```

Comment: Thank you.. looks like I should be throwing a custom message in the AuraHandledException..   Good insight!  This article was helpful too!  

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_custom_errors.htm